# Webform token formatting

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm trying to get the answers from one form, pre-filled in another form by adding tokens in the confirmation URL. This works for most answers while using the token: [webform_submission:values:?]

However one of the answers I need to pre-fill is based on a content type (Entity select question), instead of sending just the node number of the content type, it sends 'node 101' (node%3A**101**) in the URL. I need the 'node%3A' part to disappear in order for the pre-fill to work.

This is how my confirmation URL looks like: /thank-you/?destination=[webform_submission:values:destination:raw]&e_mail=[webform_submission:values:e_mail]

The e-mail token works, the destination token not. If I leave the raw part out it will send both the destination name and the node in the URL, you will then get something like this: Sri%20Lanka%20%28**101**%29. The node of this content type (Sri Lanka) is 101.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `:urlencode` suffix and change `[webform_submission:values:e_mail]` to `[webform_submission:values:e_mail:urlencode]`

Comment: It is the destination that is the problem (not the email). So this part [webform_submission:values:destination:raw] gets me this URL: ....?bestemming=Sri Lanka (101)&... while it should become just ....?bestemming=101&...

The weird thing is if I check the logs what is posted is actually 101, however what it gets is Sri Lanka (101). 

I'm now wondering if this is a webforms problem, or that I have some general settings that cause this to happen.